# Excel VBA - Adding username to now() Timestamp ruins formatting?

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, timestamp, spreadsheet

I've got a system in which i want to generate a random RA number when a generate button is pressed. This RA number is the date backwards, then the time. I formatted these to take out the /'s and :'s so it is one long number.

For example now, it would generate to: 202009251119

However, to make this more unique, i want to add the username onto the end. So i edited the code to this:

Range("I12:J12").Value = Now() & Application.UserName

Whilst this works, it then changes the formatting, and it looks like this:

2020/09/25 11:19 'Username'

How can i add this username whilst keeping the formatting so it's still an RA code?

Comment: Did you mean `Range("I12:J12").Value = FORMAT(Now(),"YYYYMMDDHHmmSS") & Application.UserName`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Range("I12:J12").Value = Format(Now(), "yyyymmddhhmm") & Application.UserName
End Sub
```

[image]

If you want, you could insert a space between the date and the name.